# help positioning the search bar

Tags: html, css, web

I have my navigation bar using unordered links and using jquery for ui effects. This works fine. Now I have designed a search bar which matches the theme of the bar and wanna position it to the right of the nav bar. kinda like the vimeo website..

The problem is that i cannot include it in the same list cos i dont want the jquery effects to be applied to the search bar. How do i position it to the right of nav bar??

Heres the css i tried but doesnt work

```
.search{
background-image:url('search.jpg');
margin-top:inherit;
margin-left:inherit;

width:200px;
height:40px;

}
```

here goes the html

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="searchField" />
    <img src="go.jpg" alt="Search" onclick="alert('You clicked on search button')"         /></div>
```

Comment: Please put your HTML as well, it's extremely difficult to answer otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple options The best option depends on your entire layout. Here are two basic CSS implementations of horizontal navigation list and search inline with each other.

**HTML**

```
<div id="Navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="search">
        <input type="text" id="searchField" />
        <img src="go.jpg" alt="Search" onclick="alert('You clicked on search button')" />
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

**CSS Float**

```
#Navigation ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#Navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
#Navigation ul li a
{
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
}
.search 
{
    background-image:url('search.jpg');
    float: right;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
}
```

**CSS Absolute**

```
#Navigation
{
    position: relative;
}
#Navigation ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#Navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
#Navigation ul li a
{
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
}
.search 
{
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url('search.jpg');
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
}
```

Comment: sorry.. this just puts the search box all the way to the right.. I have margins to the right of the site.. and its NOT in the same vertical plane as the navigation bar..

Comment: Did you clear the float? Also post your code for the nav and parent container. It would help.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks a lot for your reply anyways!