# how to position a search bar in html/css

Tags: html, css

This is my code so far:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home_style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
    <div class="search_bar">
        <input type="text" name="search" value="search">
</div>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html,body{
height:100%;
min-height:100%; 
width:100%
min-width:100%;
}

.header{
margin-bottom:0;
height:10%; 
width:100%;
background-color:#343430;
}

.search_bar input[type="text"]{
position:relative;  
left:20%;
top:25%;
width:30%;

background-color:white; 
color:grey;
}
```

How do I make the search bar be positioned further down, i need the search bar to be positioned in the middle of the header not the top. Why is top:25% not working?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085160/positioning-of-search-bar][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276531/help-positioning-the-search-bar][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085160/positioning-of-search-bar
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276531/help-positioning-the-search-bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `position:relative` with `position:absolute`:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100% min-width:100%;
}
.header {
    margin-bottom:0;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#343430;
}
.search_bar input[type="text"] {
    position:absolute;
    left:20%;
    top:25%;
    width:30%;
    background-color:white;
    color:grey;
}
```

If you look at the definition for relative positioning:

```
The element is positioned relative to its normal position,
so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position
```

your search bar was really positioning itself.

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/y8kDv/)

Comment: What's the difference between making it relative and absolute. It works but I was just wondering.

Comment: @user3247608 Read [this.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)  Absolute: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.  Relative: The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position.

PS: You're supposed to mark the answer that works as "correct".

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by ancestor element? I think I ticked the icon that marks the answer as correct

Comment: @user3247608 An ancestor element is the element it's in (the parent element), here's a better definition: Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.


Basically, it's not held in constraint with the element it's in's boundaries.  Hope this helped!